# Include the track changes in word using python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, office-automation

I am trying to extract some part of a document and put it into a table in Excel. So far so good, I was able to do it.

However, when I change something in the text with "track changes" in word the python code does not include that changes. I want to have the track changes visible in the table as well.

Here how it works now:

[image]

But I have changed the text with track changes in word and I want that to be included so it will be like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if that works, if so, how?

Thanks in advance!
Best regards,
Thor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TrackRevisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.trackrevisions) property of the `Document` class from the Word object model:

```
'Turn on Track Changes
WordApplication.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
```

And you may turn them off:

```
'Turn off Track Changes
WordApplication.ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
```